# Did I should encode the string before assign it to a asp.net TextBox

Tags: asp.net

1、Because allow users to type in html tags like `<script>` and so on,So I disabled the   asp.net validate Request in web.config.

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
 <pages validateRequest="false"/>
```

2、In order to prevent from `xss` attacking ,I have added `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode string.

3、In my web application Users can add and edit themselves's articles.But I do not sure If I should encode at the page load phase for the TextBox in the ArticleEdit.aspx page.

e.g:

ArticleEdit.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" id="articleTitle" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ArticleEdit.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string titleText = "<script>alert('1111');</script>"; //string "<script>alert('1111');</script>" is fetched from DB;
            articleTitle.Value = titleText;

        }
```

Questions 1:

Did I shoud encode the titleText string like below?

```
string titleText =HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<script>alert('1111');</script>"); 
articleTitle.Value = titleText;
```

Questions 2:

If encode the string.After page load complete ,user will seen an encoded string
 `&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;1111&#39;);&lt;/script&gt;`
instead of `"<script>alert('1111');</script>"`.

How to solve this?

Sorry for my bad english.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did I shoud encode the titleText string like below?

No, you don't need to encode anything if you are assigning it to the `Value` property of a TextBox. The WebControl will automatically encode it before displaying.